# Issue in Weblogic Workshop 10.3, Weblogic Portlet development

Tags: java, portlet, weblogic-10.x

I am configuring Weblogic Portlets in Weblogic Workshop 10.3.
I have all the projects configured and the EAR project specified.
In my main Portal Project, I am constantly getting the following errors while compilation.

e.g.

"beehive-controls-1.0.1-10.0" library is on the classpath of this project, but is not in the weblogic-application.xml file of the EAR project ""

I have done all checks and the library name is mentioned the weblogic-application.xml file.  I tried googling but to no avail.  Please let me know if any more information is required.

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: can you post the section of weblogic-application.xml pointing to beehive? Might be a typo in there?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the file system. Just delete (take a backup) the weblogic-application.xml from the workspace folder.
And then you can right click the error and do a quick fix to add the library to the weblogic-application.xml file. And do a build.
This fixed the problem for me.. Hope it does for you too!! :)